# How can I split a string into multiple parts in python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split

I'm having problems splitting my names up by their listed order, name and their exam score.

I did the following in my code: `print repr(names)` in a loop to get the following 6 lines of data

```
'1 Name 559/1 '
'2 Name 484/1 '
'3 Name N'ame 444/2 '
'4 Name 400/1 '
'5 Name Name 928/5 '
'6 Name Name-Name 1292/10 '
```

I want to be able to split them up but I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lsplit'`

I've had a go using lsplit, rsplit and split but I can't get it to work...

In the end result names will be turned into 3 variables: `names_index`, `name` and `names_score`

Anyone know how I can acheive this?

Thanks - Hyflex

**EDIT**

```
for item in listitems:
    if item.find("strong"):
        names = str(item.text)
        names = items .split("\n")
        for name in names:
            clean_name = name.lstrip(" ")
            print repr(clean_name)
            student_number = clean_name.lsplit(" ", 1)
            student_score = clean_name.rsplit(" ", 1)
            #student_name = clean_name.lsplit(" ", 1) # Unsure how to get the last part..
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `str.lsplit` because `str.split` already goes from the left.

For each string, just call `.split()` and you will get a list with `[names_index, name, names_score]`

If the pattern  is `number / words / more numbers`, then you can use regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> filter(None, re.split(r'(\d+) (\w.*) (\d.*)', '1 Name 559/1 '))
['1', 'Name', '559/1 ']
>>> filter(None, re.split(r'(\d+) (\w.*) (\d.*)', '6 Name Name-Name 1292/10 '))
['6', 'Name Name-Name', '1292/10 ']
```

Comment: The problem with that is that sometimes my names have spaces in their names and/or symbols in their name.

Comment: @Hyflex Could the names have numbers in it?

Comment: No I dont think my students will ever have numbers in their names, Edited to show my example what I tried.

Comment: @justhalf Can you please stop being rude? OP gets a notification when someone answers his question

Comment: @Haidro that looks like it, I totally forgot about using a regex to do it. Could you explain how that regex works, I just looked through http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html but can't figure out how yours is working.

Comment: @Hyflex `(\d+)` matches a digit (the `+` is for more than one digit numbers), `(\w.*)` matches the name. We use `.*` instead of `+` so we can get the spaces. Finally, the `(\d.*)` gets the last digits

Comment: Green tick awarded, I can't find anything anywhere what mentions the use of filter(None, x)

Comment: @Hyflex Ah, that just gets rid of the empty strings in the list returned by `re.split()`

Comment: @Hyflex Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

Answer (score 3):

rsplit returns the splitted result, not only the last part. So you are actually going in the right direction.

For your code where you might have space in your name, you can do this:

```
the_string = the_string.strip()
[id, name_score] = the_string.split(' ',1) # Split into ['1', 'name name 654/1']
[name, score] = name_score.rsplit(' ',1)   # Split into ['name name','654/1']
```

so, for input `6 Name Name-Name 1292/10' your intended values are already there:

```
id # this is '6'
name # this is 'Name Name-name'
score # this is '1292/10'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the issue here

Comment: Yes, this will get your intended parts, right? id, name, and score.

Comment: Yes, this works too. I've opted for the regex version by @Haidro but yours works good aswell :)

Answer (score 3):

Its as easy as -

```
>>> s = '4 Name 400/1 '
>>> names_index, name, names_score = s.split()
>>> names_index, name, names_score
('4', 'Name', '400/1')
>>>
```

As Haidro said, there is no function as lsplit, use split instead.

Answer (score 3):

you can operate this way with your list

```
>>> names = ['1 Name 559/1 ',
'2 Name 484/1 ',
'3 Name Naaame 444/2 ',
'4 Name 400/1 ',
'5 Name Name 928/5 ',
'6 Name Name-Name 1292/10 ']
>>> names_lst=[]
>>> for n in names:
    names_lst+=n.split()
```

gives

```
>>> names_lst
['1', 'Name', '559/1', '2', 'Name', '484/1', '3', 'Name', 'Naaame', 
 '444/2', '4', 'Name', '400/1', '5', 'Name', 'Name', '928/5', '6', 'Name', 
 'Name-Name', '1292/10', ['1', 'Name', '559/1'], ['2', 'Name', '484/1'], 
 ['3', 'Name', 'Naaame', '444/2'], ['4', 'Name', '400/1'],
 ['5', 'Name', 'Name', '928/5'], ['6', 'Name', 'Name-Name', '1292/10']]
```

Comment: Problem there is that the names should be combined not split up. Edited to show my example what I tried.